# Where can I find a list of all the Superman comics' shield numbers?

Tags: suggested-order, dc, superman

In roughly 2008, DC started cross-comic stories amongst the *Superman* family titles.  To help readers keep track of the order of these stories, DC put a shield with a number in it on the cover.  This is similar to what they did back in the 90's with triangle numbers when they had Superman stories going on that crossed all of the Superman titles of the time.

I'm trying to catch up on my comic book reading, and so I'm reading comics from 2009-2011, and I need a reference list of how the Superman titles are ordered so I can read them in order.  Can someone point me to such a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website [Comic Binding](http://comicbinding.com/mapping/superman-new-krypton) has the complete list of the shield numbers for the Superman comics published starting in 2008. The list is rather long and a formatting nightmare, you can [**READ IT HERE**](http://comicbinding.com/mapping/superman-new-krypton), or see here:

```
Green numbers:
1 - New Krypton #1
2 - Superman #681
3 - Guardian Special #1
4 - Action Comics #871
5 - Supergirl #35
6 - Superman #682
7 - Action Comics #872
8 - Supergirl #36
9 - Superman #683
10 - Action Comics #873
11 - Supergirl #37 (no number)
12 - Superman #684
13 - Action Comics #874
14 - Supergirl #38
15 - Superman #685 (no number)
16 - World of New Krypton #1
17 - Action Comics #875
18 - Supergirl #39
19 - Superman #686
20 - World of New Krypton #2
21 - Action Comics #876
22 - Supergirl #40
23 - Superman #687
24 - World of New Krypton #3
25 - Action Comics #877
26 - Supergirl #41
27 - Superman #688
28 - World of New Krypton #4
29 - Action Comics #878
30 - Supergirl #42
31 - Superman #689
32 - World of New Krypton #5
33 - Action Comics #879
34 - Supergirl #43
35 - Superman #690

Red numbers:
0 - Superman Secret Files 2009
1 - World of New Krypton #6
2 - Action Comics #880
3 - Supergirl #44
4 - Superman #691
5 - Jimmy Olsen #2
6 - World of New Krypton #7
7 - Action Comics #881
8 - Supergirl #45
9 - Superman #692
10 - World of New Krypton #8
11 - Action Comics #882
12 - Supergirl #46
13 - Superman #693
14 - World of New Krypton #9
15 - Action Comics #883
16 - Supergirl #47
17 - Superman #694
18 - World of New Krypton #10
19 - Action Comics #884
20 - Supergirl #48
21 - Superman #695
22 - World of New Krypton #11
23 - Action Comics #885
24 - Supergirl #49
25 - Superman #696
26 - World of New Krypton #12
27 - Action Comics #886
28 - Supergirl #50
29 - Superman #697
30 - Adventure Comics #8
31 - Last Stand of Krypton #1
32 - Action Comics #887
33 - Supergirl #51
34 - Superman #698
35 - Adventure Comics #9
36 - Last Stand of New Krypton #2
37 - Action Comics #888
38 - Adventure Comics #10
39 - Supergirl #52
40 - Superman #699
41 - Last Stand of Krypton #3
42 - Action Comics #889
43 - Adventure Comics #11
```

Comment: [This](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7908/1027) answer shows a way to include looooong lists in answers which triggers a nested scrollbox.  Tomorrow I'll edit up this answer to have the full list.