# In what order should Buffy and Angel be watched?

Tags: suggested-order, buffy-the-vampire-slayer, angel

I had the luxury of watching Buffy and Angel when they were on television, when it was impossible for me to mess up the viewing order.  Now that I'm introducing it to some friends (and we're coming up on the beginning of Angel) I have no idea when I should watch what episodes, to ensure everything makes sense.

Does anyone know (or have a reference to) a good viewing order for watching Buffy and Angel at the same time?

Comment: [Which is the best Buffy/Angel viewing order?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/205932/112094)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Angel series 1 began alongside Buffy series 4, and to watch "as aired" you should alternate from that point, starting with Buffy.  However, there isn't so much crossover that you *need* to; in general if you want to watch in 'spurts' then one DVD of 3-4 episodes at a time will work fine; even 6-7 in later series.

There are a couple of crossover points to watch out for, though.  As Buffy aired first, all crossover episodes should be watched Buffy, then Angel.  A complete list:

(Bx.y is Buffy, series x, episode y. Ax.y is Angel.)

**Buffy series 1**

A lot of this series can be skipped if you're in a hurry, as the writing was still finding it's feet; Buffy didn't become a consistently must-watch series until around series 2, episode 3.  That said, it had moments of wit and brilliance right from the start.

- Don't miss B1.7 *Angel* or B1.12 *Prophecy Girl*, as both are strong episodes with material that will matter later.

**Buffy series 2-3**

The finale of Buffy series 3 contains the setup and motivations for the Angel spinoff.

**Buffy series 4 / Angel series 1**

- Technically there's a 5-second crossover in B4.1 *The Freshman* and A1.1 *City of*, but it's a character beat; no plots will be spoiled if you don't watch them together.
- B4.3 *Harsh Light of Day* is immediately followed by A1.3 *In the Dark* in the timeline, and characters move from one to the other.  You must watch the Buffy episode first, but it won't ruin anything if you finish B4.4 before watching the Angel.
- B4.8 *Pangs* and A1.8 *I Will Remember You* are a crossover story. Catch up to the end of episode 7 in both series before you start.
- B4.15 *This Year's Girl* & 16 *Who Are You* are a two-parter.  This doesn't synchronise precisely with Angel, but MUST be watched before A1.18 *Five By Five* & 19 *Sanctuary*, which are a follow-on story.  B4.20 *The Yoko Factor* then follows from the end of *Sanctuary*, so it's probably best to just watch in one-episode alternation from 17-20.

**Buffy series 5 / Angel series 2**

We've done the hard part; much less crossover from now on.  As of this point the 'previously on Buffy' segments started giving away **huge** spoilers for the episode by their choice of 'previously' clip.  If possible, start skipping them.

- B5.7 *Fool for Love* and A2.7 *Darla* form a triptych.  While not *technically* a crossover, and both episodes will make sense on their own, the emotional impact of taking them together is huge, as the Angel episode forces you to re-evaluate things you just saw in the Buffy episode.  I strongly recommend watching these two as aired, together in a single session.
- A2.9 *Trial* should be watched before B5.14 *Crush* to avoid a minor spoiler.
- B5.17 *Forever* is a crossover. It won't spoil any *plots* if the series are out of sync at this point, but Angel's *character* will seem wrong if you haven't finished A2.16 *Epiphany* yet.
- B5.22 *The Gift* is not a crossover, but it is an exception to my advice earlier - the 'previously on' is actually an important part of the theme and presentation of this episode, and should NOT be skipped.

**Buffy series 6 / Angel series 3**

The shows were now showing on different networks, so no direct crossovers happened. There's an implied one offstage around episode 3 of each series, but order doesn't matter.

**Buffy series 7 / Angel series 4**

Last series of Buffy.  Not much direct crossover, but some implied timing of events. As the big finale approaches they start to sync up again, but the timeline does not match up if you watch identical episode numbers as it did earlier.

- A4.15 *Orpheus* is a crossover, and happens immediately before B7.18 *Dirty Girls*.  The timeline is most consistent if you watch as far as B7.17 *Lies My Parents Told Me* before watching *Orpheus*, but there won't be any confusion if you don't.
- The series end is an exception to the usual timing; the Angel finale A4.22 *Home* happens in the timeline just before the Buffy finale B7.21 *End of Days* and B7.22 *Chosen*, in which Angel appears.

It won't actually spoil or confuse any plots if you watch as-aired; you'll just see Angel turn up in Buffy with a McGuffin you haven't yet seen him acquire.  That said, for tone alone I strongly recommend watching the Angel finale before the Buffy one, as the Buffy finale brings a close emotionally to the entire series.

**Angel series 5**

Now on its own.

- A5.11 *Damage* and A5.20 *The Girl in Question* have some offstage post-Buffy continuity for those who wanted to know.

Comment: Just finished re-watching all these myself, with someone who'd missed them the first time.  Possibly it shows.

Comment: Clearly there is at least one hardcore Buffyverse fan here. :-)

Comment: a possible minor correction for B7/A4 timeline. Netflix streaming lists B7.18 as "Dirty Girls", but the answer above says B7.17. The crossover I saw starts with B7.17 "Lies my parents told me" and then continues on A4.15 "Orpheus". I saw it out of order and it isn't a big deal. But since it is a two episode skew, I thought it was worth pointing out for others.

Comment: This suffers from serious "Your answer is in another castle" syndrome, so I won't post it as one, but there's a pretty nice representation on [this one blog that I found](http://josswhedon.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/buffy-and-angel-episode-viewing-order.html)

Comment: [Which is the best Buffy/Angel viewing order?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/205932/112094)

Answer (score 10):

From [Buffyfest](http://buffyfest.blogspot.com/2009/04/buffyangel-episode-watching-guide.html) blog:

> After watching the first 3 seasons of Buffy, move on to this order. This is order is designed for minimum disc switching.
>
> ## Seasons 4/1
>
> Buffy Season 4 - The Freshman
>   Angel Season 1 - City of...
>   Angel Season 1 -Lonely Hearts
>   Buffy Season 4 - Living Conditions
>   Buffy Season 4 - The Harsh Light Of Day
>   Angel Season 1 -IN THE DARK
>   Angel Season 1 -I FALL TO PIECES
>   Buffy Season 4 - Fear Itself
>   Buffy Season 4 - Beer Bad
>   Buffy Season 4 - Wild at Heart
>   Buffy Season 4 - The Initiative
>   Angel Season 1 -RM W/A VU
>   Angel Season 1 -Sense and Sensitivity
>   Angel Season 1 -The Bachelor Party
>   Buffy Season 4 - Pangs
>   Angel Season 1 -I Will Remember You
>   Buffy Season 4 - Something Blue
>   Angel Season 1 -Hero
>   Angel Season 1 -Parting Gifts
>   Buffy Season 4 - Hush
>   Buffy Season 4 – Doomed
>   Buffy Season 4 - A New Man
>   Angel Season 1 -Somnambulist
>   Angel Season 1 -Expecting
>   Angel Season 1 -She
>   Buffy Season 4 - The I In Team
>   Buffy Season 4 - Goodbye Iowa
>   Angel Season 1 -I've Got You Under My Skin
>   Angel Season 1 -The Prodigal
>   Angel Season 1 -The Ring
>   Angel Season 1 -Eternity
>   Buffy Season 4 - This Year's Girl (1 of 2)
>   Buffy Season 4 - Who Are You? (2 of 2)
>   Buffy Season 4 - Superstar
>   Buffy Season 4 - Where the Wild Things
>   Angel -Five by Five (part 1 of 2)
>   Buffy Season 4 - New Moon Rising
>   Angel -Sanctuary (part 2 of 2)
>   Buffy Season 4 - The Yoko Factor
>   Angel Season 1 -War Zone
>   Angel Season 1 -Blind Date
>   Buffy Season 4 - Primeval
>   Buffy Season 4 - Restless
>   Angel Season 1 -To Shanshu in LA
>
> ## Seasons 5/2
>
> Buffy Season 5 Episode 1: Buffy vs. Dracula
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 2: Real Me
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 3: The Replacement
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 4: Out of My Mind
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 1: Judgment
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 2: Are You Now or Have You Ever Been
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 3: First Impressions
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 4: Untouched
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 5: No Place Like Home
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 6: Family
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 5: Dear Boy
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 6: Guise Will Be Guise
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 7: Fool for Love
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 7: Darla
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 8: Shadow
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 9: Listening to Fear
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 10: Into the Woods
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 11: Triangle
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 12: Checkpoint
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 13: Blood Ties
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 8: The Shroud of Rahmon
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 9: The Trial
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 10: Reunion
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 11: Redefinition
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 14: Crush
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 12: Blood Money
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 13: Happy Anniversary
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 14: The Thin Dead Line
>   Angel Season 2 pisode 15: Reprise
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 16: Epiphany
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 17: Disharmony
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 15: I Was Made to Love You
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 16: The Body
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 17: Forever
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 18: Dead End
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 19: Belonging
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 18: Intervention
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 19: Tough Love
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 20: Over the Rainbow
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 21: Through the Looking Glass
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 20: Spiral
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 21: The Weight of the World
>   Buffy Season 5 Episode 22: The Gift
>   Angel Season 2 Episode 22: There's No Place Like Plrtz Glrb
>
> **note: Although some may not agree, the narrative flow is actually better if you watch "Darla" BEFORE "Fool For Love" (or if you have any skill at math with regards to calculating Angel's age)
>
> ## Seasons 6/3
>
> Angel Season 3 Episode 1: Heartthrob
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 1: Bargaining: Part 1
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 2: Bargaining: Part 2
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 3: After Life
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 2: That Vision Thing
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 3: That Old Gang of Mine
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 4: Carpe Noctem
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 4: Flooded
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 5: Life Serial
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 5: Fredless
>
> (at this point you can watch them however you want until mid season 7 of Buffy [indicated] as Buffy moved to UPN. I grouped them into fours so it's still not as much disc switching...but feel free to watch 8 Angels in a row if you're into the story more, or vice versa)
>
> Angel Season 3 Episode 6: Billy
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 7: Offspring
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 8: Quickening
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 6: All the Way
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 7: Once More, with Feeling
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 8: Tabula Rasa
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 9: Lullaby
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 10: Dad
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 11: Birthday
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 12: Provider
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 9: Smashed
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 10: Wrecked
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 11: Gone
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 12: Doublemeat Palace
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 13: Waiting in the Wings
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 14: Couplet
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 15: Loyalty
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 16: Sleep Tight
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 13: Dead Things
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 14: Older and Far Away
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 15: As You Were
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 16: Hell's Bells
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 17: Forgiving
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 18: Double or Nothing
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 19: The Price
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 20: A New World
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 17: Normal Again
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 18: Entropy
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 19: Seeing Red
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 20: Villains
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 21: Benediction
>   Angel Season 3 Episode 22: Tomorrow
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 21: Two to Go
>   Buffy Season 6 Episode 22: Grave
>
> ## Seasons 7/4
>
> Angel Season 4, Episode 1: Deep Down
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 2: Ground State
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 3: The House Always Wins
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 4: Slouching Toward Bethlehem
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 1: Lessons
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 2: Beneath You
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 3: Same Time, Same Place
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 4: Help
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 5: Supersymmetry
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 6: Spin the Bottle
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 5: Selfless
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 6: Him
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 7: Conversations with Dead People
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 8: Sleeper
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 9: Never Leave Me
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 10: Bring on the Night
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 11: Showtime
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 12: Potential
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 13: The Killer in Me
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 14: First Date
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 15: Get It Done
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 16: Storyteller
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 7: Apocalypse, Nowish
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 8: Habeas Corpses
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 9: Long Day's Journey
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 10: Awakening
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 11: Soulless
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 12: Calvary
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 13: Salvage
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 14: Release
>
> (Start watching in this order again around or before here.)
>
> Buffy Season 7, Episode 17: Lies My Parents Told Me
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 15: Orpheus
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 18: Dirty Girls
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 19: Empty Places
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 20: Touched
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 16: Players
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 17: Inside Out
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 18: Shiny Happy People
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 19: The Magic Bullet
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 20: Sacrifice
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 21: Peace Out
>   Angel Season 4, Episode 22: Home
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 21: End of Days
>   Buffy Season 7, Episode 22: Chosen
>
> Then all of season 5 Angel (in order, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Angel season 1 started along side Buffy season 4 (he left Buffy at the end of season 3...spoilers).  I actually had this situation when I tried to introduce my wife to both buffy and angel.  We watched Buffy seasons 1-3, and then alternated between each show starting on Buffy season 4/Angel season 1.  That allowed us to watch in "real-time" with the show (Angel appears in a season 4 episode of Buffy; she visits him in the next episode of Angel, etc.)  It was a little bit jarring going from one show to another, but hey, that is how it happened when they originally aired.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, watch Buffy all the way through, then go back and watch Angel all the way through. Buffy isn't going to blow anything important for Angel, but Angel does have a few more spoilers for Buffy.