# How many named characters are there in A Song of Ice and Fire?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Has anyone ever counted how many named characters there are in the Song of Ice and Fire books? I can imagine it being hundreds or even passing a thousand with many of the names only mentioned once.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### 2102.

As per [this full list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K8DJTFUUIZvQsgnkxv3d-142SXTcmnTV4YuHsNubHjA/edit?pref=2&pli=1#gid=688707816), which also includes characters named in *The Hedge Knight*, *The Princess and the Queen*, and *The Rogue Prince* (bringing the total to **2302**).

Very big tip of the hat to Reddit user [Mynotoar](https://www.reddit.com/user/Mynotoar) for compiling this list!

Here are all the names in order of appearance (the full list contains much more detail, but no more will fit the 30,000 character limit).

---

Gared
Waymar Royce
Will
Brandon Stark
Mance Rayder
Nan
Robb Stark
Jon Snow
Eddard Stark
Theon Greyjoy
Robert Baratheon
Jory Cassel
Hullen
Harwin
Rodrik Cassel
Rickon Stark
Desmond
Catelyn Stark
Brandon Stark
Arya Stark
Sansa Stark
Luwin
Jon Arryn
Aerys Targaryen
Hoster Tully
Pycelle
Brynden Tully
Benjen Stark
Lysa Arryn
Cersei Lannister
Tommen Baratheon
Daenerys Targaryen
Illyrio Mopatis
Viserys Targaryen
Drogo
Rhaegar Targaryen
Elia Martell
Willem Darry
Aegon Targaryen
Moro
Rhogoro
Jorah Mormont
Jaime Lannister
Sandor Clegane
Tyrion Lannister
Balon Greyjoy
Rickard Stark
Lyanna Stark
Howland Reed
Tywin Lannister
Joffrey Baratheon
Myrcella Baratheon
Daeron Targaryen
Edmure Tully
Brandon Stark
Arthur Dayne
Ashara Dayne
Mordane
Beth Cassel
Lew
Donnis
Serwyn
Ryam Redwyne
Aemon Targaryen
Erryk Cargyll
Arryk Cargyll
Gerold Hightower
Barristan Selmy
Boros Blount
Gage
Mikken
Walder
Stannis Baratheon
Renly Baratheon
Petyr Baelish
Aethelmure
Chayle
Ayrmidon
Irri
Jhiqui
Doreah
Haggo
Cohollo
Qotho
Alyn
Wylla
Baelor Targaryen
Varys
Yoren
Loren
Mern
Morrec
Vayon Poole
Hallis Mollen
Mycah
Ilyn Payne
Daeryssa
Naerys Targaryen
Morgil
Raymun Darry
Moreo Tumitis
Aron Santagar
Maegor Targaryen
Loras Tyrell
Grenn
Alliser Thorne
Jeren
Todder
Dareon
Pypar
Halder
Jeor Mormont
Aemon
Donal Noye
Cotter Pyke
Bowen Marsh
Mace Tyrell
Helman Tallhart
Galbart Glover
Wyman Manderly
Jaremy Rykker
Jyck
Maege Mormont
Yohn Royce
Denys Mallister
Jeyne Poole
Jacks
Porther
Tomard
Syrio Forel
Aegon Targaryen
Maekar Targaryen
Colemon
Jaehaerys Targaryen
Aegon Targaryen
Malleon
Hugh
Rast
Albett
Samwell Tarly
Randyll Tarly
Qhorin
Mathis Rowan
Janos Slynt
Lann
Margaery Tyrell
Varly
Beric Dondarrion
Tobho Mott
Gendry
Masha Heddle
Jason Mallister
Patrek Mallister
Shella Whent
Walder Frey
Marillion
Alia
Jonos Bracken
Gregor Clegane
Thoros
Balon Swann
Bryce Caron
Andar Royce
Robar Royce
Horas Redwyne
Hobber Redwyne
Jared Frey
Hosteen Frey
Danwell Frey
Emmon Frey
Theo Frey
Martyn Rivers
Jalabhar Xho
Lothor Brune
Moon Boy
Lancel Lannister
Dacks
Anguy
Cayn
Chiggen
Bronn
Mohor
Willis Wode
Kurleket
Lharys
Godwyn
Roose Bolton
Tanda Stokeworth
Donnel Waynwood
Nestor Royce
Mya Stone
Mychel Redfort
Lyn Corbray
Vardis Egen
Heward
Wyl
Chataya
Barra
Selyse Baratheon
Tregar
Joseth
Kyra
Bessa
Stiv
Hali
Osha
Farlen
Quent
Wallen
Wayn
Mord
Albar Royce
Eon Hunter
Anya Waynwood
Martyn Cassel
Theo Wull
Ethan Glover
Mark Ryswell
Willam Dustin
Oswell Whent
Alyssa Arryn
? Vance
Clement Piper
Morton Waynwood
Gueren
Matthar
Hobb
Cuger
Clydas
Chett
Gunthor
Gurn
Shagga
Dolf
Conn
Coratt
Torrek
Jaggot
Karyl Vance
Arys Oakheart
Joss
Marq Piper
Gladden Wylde
Lothar Mallery
Jonquil
Florian
Tya Lannister
Gowen Baratheon
Ogo
Fogo
Jommo
Preston Greenfield
Kevan Lannister
Qos
Cellador
Othell Yarwyck
Borcas
Dickon Tarly
Dywen
Mandon Moore
Othor
Shella
Jafer Flowers
Bass
Hake
Ketter
Rickard Karstark
Harrion Karstark
Eddard Karstark
Torrhen Karstark
Medger Cerwyn
Robin Flint
Robett Glover
Halys Hornwood
Jon Umber
Byan Votyris
Quaro
Rakharo
Bharbo
Wylis Manderly
Wendel Manderly
Chella
Ulf
Umar
Timett
Timett
Flement Brax
Roland Crakehall
Tytos Lannister
Addam Marbrand
Gyles Rosby
Dontos Hollard
Stevron Frey
Tytos Blackwood
Doran Martell
Lewyn Martell
Rhaenys Targaryen
Perwyn Frey
Ryger Rivers
Olyvar Frey
Elmar Frey
Endrew Tarth
Pate
Rudge
Harren Hoare
Jhogo
Mago
Jhaqo
Mirri Maz Duur
Marwyn
Leo Lefford
Podrick Payne
Shae
Lewys Lydden
? Serrett
Jon Umber
Daryn Hornwood
Dacey Mormont
Gawen Westerling
Quenten Banefort
Garth Greenfield
Regenard Estren
Tytos Brax
Mallor
Eroeh
Pono
Buu
Symeon
Jon Stark
Rickard Stark
Theon Stark
Brandon Stark
Brandon Stark
Rodrik Stark
Torrhen Stark
Cregan Stark
Harys Swyft
Andros Brax
Forley Prester
Vargo Hoat
Amory Lorch
Vyman
Bethany Rowan
Orys Baratheon
Argilac Durrandon
Shireen Baratheon
Tyrek Lannister
Joanna Lannister
Dorna Lannister
Willem Lannister
Martyn Lannister
Janei Lannister
Genna Frey
Cleos Frey
Tion Frey
Tygett Lannister
Darlessa Marbrand
Gerion Lannister
Joy Hill
Stafford Lannister
Cerenna Lannister
Myrielle Lannister
Daven Lannister
Creylen
Jeyne Arryn
Rowena Arryn
Harwyn Hoare
Arrec Durrandon
Edmyn Tully
Minisa Tully
Desmond Grell
Robin Ryger
Utherydes Wayn
Garth Gardener
Harlen Tyrell
Alerie Tyrell
Willas Tyrell
Garlan Tyrell
Olenna Tyrell
Mina Redwyne
Paxter Redwyne
Janna Fossoway
Garth Tyrell
Garse Flowers
Garrett Flowers
Moryn Tyrell
Gormon
Lomys
Vortimer Crane
Desmera Redwyne
Arwyn Oakheart
Leyton Hightower
Jon Fossoway
Urron Greyiron
Qhored Hoare
Vickon Greyjoy
Alannys Greyjoy
Rodrik Greyjoy
Maron Greyjoy
Asha Greyjoy
Euron Greyjoy
Victarion Greyjoy
Aeron Greyjoy
Nymeria
Mors Martell
Daeron Targaryen
Myriah Martell
Mellario Martell
Arianne Martell
Quentyn Martell
Trystane Martell
Aegon Targaryen
Oberyn Martell
Areo Hotah
Caleotte
Edric Dayne
Visenya Targaryen
Rhaenys Targaryen
Aenys Targaryen
Jaehaerys Targaryen
Viserys Targaryen
Aegon Targaryen
Rhaenyra Targaryen
Daeron Targaryen
Viserys Targaryen
Aerys Targaryen
Rhaella Targaryen
Cressen
Pylos
Patchface
Dalla
Matrice
Steffon Baratheon
Jommy
Harbert
Davos Seaworth
Gulian Swann
Salladhor Saan
Morosh
Melisandre
Ardrian Celtigar
Monford Velaryon
Duram Bar Emmon
Axell Florent
Guncer Sunglass
Lommy
Hot Pie
Lollys Stokeworth
Falyse Stokeworth
Ermesande Hayford
Morros Slynt
Vylarr
Walder Frey
Walder Frey
Hayhead
Alebelly
Jammos Frey
Merrett Frey
Walder Frey
Walder Frey
Walder Rivers
Waltyr Frey
Turnip
Bandy
Shyra
Palla
Calon
TomToo
Praed
Tarber
Malcolm
Lync
Hod
William Mooton
Jaqen H'ghar
Rorge
Biter
Reysen
Cutjack
Kurz
Koss
Dobber
Redwyn
Dorren Stark
Conwy
Thoren Smallwood
Arnell
Aerion Targaryen
Burton Crakehall
Hendry Bracken
Allar Deem
Jacelyn Bywater
Murch
Allard Seaworth
Dale Seaworth
Barre
Hubard Rambton
Maric Seaworth
Matthos Seaworth
Devan Seaworth
Marya Seaworth
Bryen Farring
Azor Ahai
Nissa Nissa
Cassana Baratheon
Delena Norcross
Edric Storm
Sawane Botley
Gorold Goodbrother
Sylas
Dagmer
Helya
Qalen
Wendamyr
Lynesse Mormont
Tregar Ormollen
Pyat Pree
Xaro Xhoan Daxos
Quaithe
Eddison Tollett
Jarman Buckwell
Mallador Locke
Bedwyck
Ottyn Wythers
Woth
Gerren
Rey
Urreg
Qyle
Frenken
Ironbelly
Salloreon
Alayaya
Poxy Tym
Donella Hornwood
Domeric Bolton
Heke
Mors Umber
Hother Umber
Larence Snow
Leobald Tallhart
Benfred Tallhart
Beren Tallhart
Ondrew Locke
Lyessa Flint
Cley Cerwyn
Tallad
Hallyne
Weasel
Munciter
Malliard
Rossart
Crawn
Calor
Skittrick
Meera Reed
Jojen Reed
Shadd
Colen
Ronnet Connington
Brienne Tarth
Selwyn Tarth
Lorent Caswell
Lucas Blackwood
? Willum
Josua Willum
Elyas Willum
Steffon Varner
Guyard Morrigen
Mark Mullendore
Tanton Fossoway
Cortnay Penrose
Craster
Lark
Gilly
Nella
Bernarr
Raymun Redbeard
Bael
Gendel
Gorne
Joramun
Esgred
Sigrin
Otter Gimpknee
Bluetooth
Rymolf Stormdrunk
Uller
Qarl
Skyte
Eldiss
Wex Pyke
Rolfe
Donnel Locke
The Tickler
Chiswyck
Rafford
Dunsen
Amabel
Harra
Weese
Saathos
Quhuru Mo
Dancy
Marei
Pia
Alyn Stackspear
Wat
Dunaver
Jodge
Tothmure
Joss Stilwood
Eggon
Layna
Tobbot
Durran Godsgrief
Elenei
Rupert Brax
Lymond Vikary
Antario Jast
Osmynd
Parmen Crane
Emmon Cuy
Gawen Wylde
Alester Florent
Stygg
Werlag
Tymor
Urzen
Lorren
Gevin Harlaw
Maron Botley
Todric
Andrik
Dunstan Drumm
Lucan
Lyonel
Tuffleberry
Rymund
Enger
Delp
Lew
Poul Pemford
Myles
Mathos Mallarawan
Wendello Qar Deeth
Egon Emeros
Osmund Kettleblack
Osney Kettleblack
Osfryd Kettleblack
Bryan Fossoway
Eldon Estermont
Erren Florent
Elwood Meadows
Rattleshirt
Harma
Alfyn
Ebben
Symon
Kym
? Deremond
Mebble
Aenys Frey
Cadwyn
Ben
Shagwell
Holger
Pollitor
Drennan
Squint
Aggar
Gynir
Dalbridge
Stonesnake
Ygritte
Brandon Stark
Jeffory Mallister
Kyle Royce
Elbert Arryn
Kromm
Cadwyl
Imry Florent
Arneld
Urrathon
Sybassion
Belwas
Walton
Utt
Qyburn
Urswyck
Harys Haigh
Philip Foote
Edwyd Fossoway
Willit
Josmyn Peckledon
Bonifer Hasty
Dermot
Timon
Aurane Waters
Dykk Harlaw
Endehar
Rolfe
Harrag Sharp
Kenned
Ramsay Snow
Ballabar
Ragwyle
Edwyle Stark
Willam Stark
Artos Stark
Donnor Stark
Beron Stark
Rodwell Stark
Jonnel Stark
Barth Stark
Edwyn Stark
Jorah Stark
Jonos Stark
Brandon Stark
Walton Stark
Edderion Stark
Eyron Stark
Benjen Stark
Benjen Stark
Edrick Stark
Aemon Estermont
Alyn Estermont
Shyra Errol
Donnel Swann
Jurne
Lomas Estermont
Andrew Estermont
Stannis Seaworth
Steffon Seaworth
Lyman Darry
Halmon Paege
Berena Tallhart
Brandon Tallhart
Eddara Tallhart
Sybelle Glover
Gawen Glover
Erena Glover
Robert Brax
Igon Vyrwel
Butterbumps
Melara Florent
Alekyne Florent
Melessa Tarly
Rhea Hightower
Ryam Florent
Colin Florent
Hosman Norcross
Alester Norcross
Renly Norcross
Omer
Merrell Florent
Rylene Crane
Rycherd Crane
Waldon Wynch
Rodrik Harlaw
? Stonehouse
Norne Goodbrother
Meldred Merlyn
? Sparr
Baelor Blacktyde
Donnor Saltcliffe
? Sunderly
Marwyn Belmore
Myranda Royce
Perra Frey
Corenna Frey
Ryman Frey
Edwyn Frey
Janyce Frey
Walda Frey
Petyr Frey
Mylenda Frey
Perra Frey
Jeyne Frey
Aegon Frey
Maegelle Vance
Dafyn Vance
Marianne Vance
Walder Vance
Patrek Vance
Marsella Frey
Walton Frey
Deana Frey
Steffon Frey
Walda Frey
Bryan Frey
Tywin Frey
Willem Frey
Melesa Frey
Tyana Frey
Aegon Frey
Rhaegar Frey
Jeyne Frey
Robert Frey
Walda Frey
Jonos Frey
Perriane Haigh
Leslyn Haigh
Walder Haigh
Donnel Haigh
Alyn Haigh
Cyrenna Frey
Alys Frey
Tytos Frey
Zhoe Frey
Zia Frey
Zachery Frey
Kyra Goodbrook
Walder Goodbrook
Jeyne Goodbrook
Luceon
Amarei Frey
Bellena Frey
Arwood Frey
Ryella Frey
Ryella Frey
Androw Frey
Alyn Frey
Lythene Vypren
Lucias Vypren
Elyana Wylde
Jon Wylde
Rickard Wylde
Damon Vypren
Symond Frey
Betharios Frey
Alesander Frey
Alyx Frey
Bradamar Frey
Oro Tendyris
Wynafrei Frey
Mariya Frey
Amerei Frey
Pate
Walda Frey
Marissa Frey
Geremy Frey
Carolei Frey
Sandor Frey
Cynthea Frey
Raymund Frey
Beony Frey
Robert Frey
Malwyn Frey
Serra Frey
Sarra Frey
Cersei Frey
Alyssa Frey
Lothar Frey
Leonella Frey
Tysane Frey
Walda Frey
Emberlei Frey
Sallei Frey
Dickon Frey
Mathis Frey
Whalen Frey
Sylwa Frey
Hoster Frey
Damon Paege
Merianne Frey
Morya Brax
Robert Brax
Walder Brax
Jon Brax
Tyta Frey
Sarya Frey
Bethany Frey
Benfrey Frey
Jyanna Frey
Della Frey
Osmund Frey
Willamen
Roslin Frey
Annara Frey
Arwyn Frey
Wendel Frey
Colmar Frey
Shirei Frey
Joyeuse Frey
Aemon Rivers
Walda Rivers
Melwys
Jeyne Rivers
Ronel Rivers
Mellara Rivers
Aladale Wynch
Elron
Cugen
Paul
Blane
Grubbs
Aethan
Bannen
Softfoot
Kedge
Goady
Donnel Hill
Dirk
Karl
Ollo
Bessa
Sawwood
Maslyn
Tansy
Iggo
Kennos
Arryk
Erryk
Megga Tyrell
Alla Tyrell
Elinor Tyrell
Leonette Tyrell
Nysterica
Alyce Graceford
Alysanne Bulwer
Meredyth Crane
Taena Merryweather
Luthor Tyrell
Lenyl
Ryk
Orell
Styr
Tormund
Dalla
Val
Jarl
? Qorgyle
Orland
Mullin
Groleo
Myles Mooton
Richard Lonmouth
Jon Connington
Temmo
Khorane Sathmantes
Tristimun
Meizo Mahr
Jate Blackberry
Lucos Chyttering
Will
Hal
Warren
Sumner Crakehall
Harlan Grandison
Gerardys
Turquin
Erreck
Beldecar
Lem
Tom
Sharna
Pate
Husband
Sybell Westerling
Rolph Spicer
Raynald Westerling
Elenya Westerling
Rollam Westerling
Jeyne Stark
Mag Mar Tun Doh Weg
Lump
Toregg
Dormund
Munda
Alyn Ambrose
Arthur Ambrose
Jack-Be-Lucky
Pello
Bernarr
Talla Tarly
Mawney
Horton Redfort
Sebaston Farman
Elwood
Karlon Stark
Timeon Of Dorne
Maynard
Lymond Lychester
Ben
Erreg
Ravella Smallwood
Carellen Smallwood
Kraznys mo Nakloz
Arson
Grigg
Grazdan mo Ullhor
Grazdan
Grazdan
Grazdan
Missandei
Denys Arryn
Wilbert
Alyce
Tansy
Cass
Lanna
Jyzene
Helly
Leslyn
Bella
Errok
Zollo
Galyeon
Bethany
Aemon Costayne
Alaric
Hamish
Collio Quaynis
Tommen Lannister
Fornio
Byam Flint
Garth
Garth
Alan
Ronnel Harclay
Tim Stone
Ulmer
Dick
Simon Toyne
Oswyn
Wenda
Rolley Of Sisterton
Bill
Garth
Oss
Dyah
Ferny
Lister
Lennocks
Beck
Mudge
Merriman
Andrey Charlton
Lucas Roote
? Deddings
? Deddings
Joth
Matt
Ryn
Ormond
Dudley
Pate
Pate
Pate
Wyl
Maerie
Maerie
Becca
Will
Harsley
Nolla
Dennet
Kyle
Melly
Daemon Blackfyre
Terrence Toyne
Hareth
Hugh Grandison
? Cafferen
? Belgrave
Gilbert Farring
Lester Morrigen
Jon Darry
Belis
Garigus
Qarlton Chelsted
Alys Karstark
Deziel Dalt
Tremond Gargalen
Harmen Uller
Ulwyck Uller
Ryon Allyrion
Daemon Sand
Dagos Manwoody
Myles Manwoody
Mors Manwoody
Dickon Manwoody
Arron Qorgyle
Myria Jordayne
Larra Blackmont
Jynessa Blackmont
Ellaria Sand
Anders Yronwood
Leo Tyrell
Notch
Dick
Watty
Merrit
? Harte
Jayde
Puddingfoot
Luke
Alysanne Targaryen
Big Boil
Dan
Dick Follard
Cellador
Wynton Stout
Quort
Bodger
Del
Henk
Toefinger
Stone Thumbs
Lenn
Grey Worm
Prendahl na Ghezn
Sallor
Daario Naharis
Mero
Grazdan mo Eraz
Jenny
Gergen
Allyria Dayne
Lymond Goodbrook
Nage
? Tarbeck
Jenny
Tristifer Mudd
Tristifer Mudd
Raymar Royce
Ryles
? Roote
Andahar
Lew
Brenett
Ronnel Stout
Kyle Condon
Sedgekins
Gerald Gower
Murmison
Ambrose Butterwell
Myles Smallwood
Otto Hightower
Baelor Targaryen
Barth
? Fell
Silveraxe
Roro Uhoris
Mully
Satin
Runcel Hightower
Rodrik Flint
Tristan Mudd
Marq Rankenfell
Robin Hill
Su
Meliana
Kegs
Spare Boot
Easy
Dilly
Alyn
Henly
Henly
Pate
Owen
Danny Flint
Sherrit
Mad Axe
Rodrik Ryswell
Oznak zo Pahl
Ben Plumm
Scarb
Brella
Kaeth
Bessa
Ralph Buckler
Oswell Kettleblack
Bertram Beesbury
Samwell Spicer
Dennis Plumm
Harwyn Plumm
Peter Plumm
Lewys
Triston
Omer Blackberry
Rolland Storm
Hareth
Zei
Arron
Emrick
Duncan
Alyn Connington
Duncan Targaryen
Maelys Blackfyre
Lormelle
Cedrik Storm
Gwayne Gaunt
Jeyne Swann
Robert Stone
Elwood Harte
Jonothor Darry
Kella
Bryen
Grisel
Umfred
Lyonel Corbray
Watt
Tumberjon
Tim
Glendon Hewett
Baelor Hightower
Ghael
Cleon
Donyse
Torwynd
Quenn
Hop-Robin
Lum
Lester
Harmune
Emmett
Garse Goodbrook
Jothos Slynt
Danos Slynt
Alesander Staedmon
Togg Joth
Pyg
Three Toes
Jonelle Cerwyn
Monterys Velaryon
Maggo
Cadwyle
Triston Farwynd
Maron Volmark
? Myre
? Stonetree
? Kenning
Alyn Orkwood
Balon Tawney
Jeyne Frey
Lyonel Frey
Damion Lannister
Shiera Lannister
Lucion Lannister
Lanna Jast
Margot Peake
Titus Peake
Benedict Broom
Damon Marbrand
Tybolt Crakehall
Lyle Crakehall
Philip Plumm
Steffon Swyft
Joanna Swyft
Shierle Sarsfield
Selmond Stackspear
Steffon Stackspear
Terrence Kenning
Obara Sand
Nymeria Sand
Tyene Sand
Sarella Sand
Elia Sand
Obella Sand
Dorea Sand
Loreza Sand
Perros Blackmont
Delonne Allyrion
Nymella Toland
Ronald Vance
Hugo Vance
Ellery Vance
Kirth Vance
Robert Paege
Tristan Ryger
Norbert Vance
Theomar Smallwood
Mern Gardener
Luthor Tyrell
Elyn Tyrell
Theodore Tyrell
Lia Tyrell
Luthor Tyrell
Medwick
Olene Blackbar
Leo Blackbar
Leo Tyrell
Quentin Tyrell
Olymer Tyrell
Lysa Tyrell
Raymund Tyrell
Rickard Tyrell
Normund
Victor Tyrell
Victaria Bulwer
Jon Bulwer
Leo Tyrell
Alys Beesbury
Leona Tyrell
Lyonel Tyrell
Lucas Tyrell
Lorent Tyrell
Orton Merryweather
Eggen
Hal
Jack Bulwer
Wallace Massey
Dennett
Roone
Dryn
Mollander
Alleras
Roone
Rosey
Pate
Emma
Armen
Ebrose
Walgrave
Benedict
Vaellyn
Perestan
Mollos
Ryam
Emmond
Steffarion Sparr
Greydon Goodbrother
Gormond Goodbrother
Gran Goodbrother
Norjen
Rus
Tarle
Quellon Greyjoy
Harlon Greyjoy
? Greyjoy
Donel Greyjoy
Urrigon Greyjoy
? Greyjoy
Robin Greyjoy
Gysella Goodbrother
Gwin Goodbrother
Murenmure
? Greyjoy
Urras Ironfoot
Sylas Flatnose
Harrag Hoare
Olyvar Martell
Jeyne Fowler
Jennelyn Fowler
Ricasso
Manfrey Martell
Myles
Senelle
Jocelyn Swyft
Puckens
Shortear
Rugen
Illifer
Creighton Longbough
Herbert Bolling
Lucas Lothston
Manfryd Lothston
Shadrich
Hibald
Naggle
Galladon
Jorquen
Orbert Caswell
Colloquo Votar
Thomax
Osric Stark
Denyo Terys
Ternesio Terys
Yorko Terys
? Rykker
Lambert Turnberry
Balman Byrch
Garth Gardener
Quenton Hightower
Rennifer Longwaters
Alyn Velaryon
Danelle Lothston
Denys Darklyn
Rufus Leek
Serala
Symon Hollard
Jon Hollard
Robin Hollard
Steffon Hollard
Roelle
Dick Crabb
Humfrey Wagstaff
Gretchel
Maddy
Symond Templeton
Benedar Belmore
Samwell Stone
Ronnel Arryn
Boremund Harlaw
Hotho Harlaw
Harras Harlaw
Sigfryd Harlaw
Three-Tooth
Tristifer Botley
Harren Botley
Gwynesse Greyjoy
Theomore Harlaw
Aenar Targaryen
Beron Blacktyde
Haereg
Nagga
Rigney
Denestan
Germund Botley
Joseran
Jon Myre
Lucas Codd
Harren
Kemmett Pyke
Rodrik Freeborn
Torwold Browntooth
Melara Hetherspoon
Ossifer Plumm
Wat
Maggy
Owen Merryweather
Edgerran Oakheart
Alester Oakheart
Olyvar Oakheart
Eglantine
Gascoyne
Maron Martell
Lucamore Strong
Criston Cole
Alyse Ladybright
Cedric Payne
Lorimer
Hyle Hunt
Alyn Hunt
Ben Bushy
Richard Farrow
Will
Edmund Ambrose
Hugh Beesbury
Owen Inchfield
Clarence Crabb
Meggett
Brynden Rivers
Garrison Prester
Robin Moreland
Jon Bettley
Humfrey Swyft
Gyles
Orivel
Addison Hill
Michael Mertyns
Jeffory Norcross
Tom Costayne
Donnel
Robert Flowers
Rolland Darklyn
Dorcas
Raynard
Torbert
Ollidor
Nute
Ralf Stonehouse
Ralf Kenning
Ralf
Fralegg
Alvyn Sharp
Will Humble
Lenwood Tawney
Romny Weaver
Eldred Codd
Stonehand
Quellon Humble
Ralf
Ralf
Qarl
Sigfry Stonetree
Gylbert Farwynd
Erik Ironmaker
Thormor Ironmaker
Denys Drumm
Donnel Drumm
Dale
Roryn
Gormond Drumm
Hilmar Drumm
Harmund Sharp
Harrag Sharp
Lucifer Hardy
Rupert Crabb
Clement Crabb
Raymond Nayland
Harry Sawyer
Robin Potter
Eustace Brune
Andrey Dalt
Sylva Santagar
Garin
Gerold Dayne
Ormond Yronwood
Cletus Yronwood
Dake
Rolder
Rosamund Lannister
Umma
Luco Prestayn
Uthero
Brusco
Benedar
Gilwood Hunter
Mela
Gerold Grafton
Jon Lynderly
Edmund Waxley
Helliweg
Lucos
Harrold Hardyng
Harlan Hunter
Pate
Noho Dimittis
Portifer Woodwright
Jeyne Farman
Meribald
Willam
Robin
Owen
Jon Pox
Moroggo
Terro
Orbelo
Yna
Xhondo
Gulian
Lewys Piper
Roger Hogg
Bayard Norcross
Courtenay Greenhill
Lucantine Woodwright
Russell Merryweather
Wulfe
Ragnor Pyke
Talbert Serry
Humfrey Hewett
Falia Flowers
Cragorn
Garrett Paege
Quincy Cox
Daena Targaryen
Narbert
Gillam
Rawney
Clement
Bennet
Galladon Tarth
Alysanne Tarth
Arianne Tarth
Dagon Greyjoy
Moribald Chester
Osbert Serry
Guthor Grimm
Manfryd Yew
Raynard Ruttiger
Ellyn Tarbeck
Talea
Brea
Beqqo
Lotho Lornel
Moredo Prestayn
Roggo
Lanna
Gyloro Dothare
Gyleno Dothare
Quill
Tagganaro
Cossomo
Wat
S'vrone
Jeyne
Meralyn
Bethany
Assadora
Bellegere Otherys
Bellonara Otherys
Bellegere Otherys
Narbo
Joss
Quence
Allaquo
Sloey
Myrmello
Ezzelyno
Eustace
Kojja Mo
Ellendor
Merion
Jon Heddle
Willow Heddle
Jeyne Heddle
Wat
Will
Tansy
Pate
Jon Penny
Ben
Hugh Clifton
Bors
Timoth
Morra
Mellei
Belandra
Franklyn Fowler
Ben Beesbury
? Jordayne
Frynne
Kedry
Artys Arryn
Terrance Lynderly
Gyles Grafton
Ossy
Carrot
Byron
Morgarth
Jasper Arryn
Alys Waynwood
Elys Waynwood
Moelle
Aglantine
Melicent
Theodan Wells
Unella
Scolera
Humfrey Waters
Jate
Gunthor Hightower
Garth Hightower
Humfrey Hightower
Theobald
Gorghan
Hoke
Willam Wythers
Richard Horpe
Justin Massey
Clayton Suggs
Godry Farring
Harwood Fell
Corliss Penny
Quenton Greyjoy
Gyles Farwynd
Ygon Farwynd
Yohn Farwynd
Urek Ironmaker
Dagon Ironmaker
Symond Botley
Harlon Botley
Vickon Botley
Bennarion Botley
Balon Botley
Quellon Botley
Sargon Botley
Lucimore Botley
Ben Blacktyde
Lucas Corbray
Triston Sunderland
Godric Borrell
Rolland Longthorpe
Alesandor Torrent
Royce Coldwater
Damon Shett
Uthor Tollett
Wallace Waynwood
Eustace Hunter
Jasper Redfort
Creighton Redfort
Jon Redfort
Ysilla Redfort
Hostella Frey
Leana Frey
Haggon
Thistle
Bump
Borroq
Briar
Grisella
Meha
Runceford Redwyne
Ordello
Stalwart Shield
Reznak mo Reznak
Skahaz mo Kandaq
Galazza Galarre
Hizdahr zo Loraq
Grazdan zo Galare
Lyanna Mormont
Arnolf Karstark
Pytho Malanon
Aegor Rivers
Hugor
Serra
Gerris Drinkwater
Willam Wells
Ynys Yronwood
Gwyneth Yronwood
Archibald Yronwood
Jack Musgood
Harmond Umber
Manly Stokeworth
Jack Crabb
Rusty Flowers
Haldon
Rolly Duckfield
Motho
Mekko
Byron Swann
Munken
Aemond Targaryen
Lemore
Urho
Korra
Harry Strickland
Lomas Longstrider
Ysilla
Gella
Marq Grafton
Ben
Sigorn
Halleck
Othell
Black Fist
Cetherys
Mossador
Duran
Eladon Goldenhair
Loyal Spear
Marselen
Rylona Rhee
Khrazz
Barsena
Camarron
Goghor
Ithoke
Belaquo
Hazzea
Ben
Damon
Grunt
Alyn
Skinner
Dick
Yandry
Galendro
Malaquo Maegyr
Nyessos Vhassar
Doniphos Paenymion
Casso Mogat
Mezzara
Rommo
Mollono Yos Dob
Symon Stripeback
Wick Whittlestick
Hoarfrost Umber
? Sweet
Marlon Manderly
Theomore
Leona Manderly
Wylla Manderly
Dagon Codd
Adrack Humble
Roger Ryswell
Rickard Ryswell
Ty
Rory
Butts
Qavo Nogarys
Horonno
Benerro
Qezza
Grazhar
Mazdhan zo Loraq
Hazrak zo Loraq
Zharaq zo Loraq
Myles Toyne
Franklyn Flowers
Marq Mandrake
Balaq
Gorys Edoryen
Lysono Maar
Watkyn
Laswell Peake
Tristan Rivers
Dick Straw
Bill Bone
Myrio Myrakis
Caggo
Baqq
Greenguts
Gerrold Redback
Gerrold
Books
Bloodbeard
Yurkhaz zo Yunzak
Yezzan zo Qaggaz
Paezhar zo Myraq
Ghazdor zo Ahlaq
Morghaz zo Zherzyn
Gorzhak zo Eraz
Faezhar zo Faez
Denzo D'han
Meris
Hugh Hungerford
Lewys Lanster
Orson Stone
Will
Lucifer Long
Webber
Quenton Greyjoy
Dagon Greyjoy
Cromm
Qarl Kenning
Qarl Quickaxe
Hagen
Torgon Greyiron
Urragon Goodbrother
Lorren Longaxe
Harl
Grimtongue
Rolfe
Roggon Rustbeard
Dale
Methyso
Alios Qhaedar
Vogarro
Parquello Vaelaros
Belicho Staegone
Trianna
Oppo
Penny
Jace
Garth
Therry
Bartimus
Osgood Arryn
Brandon Stark
Wynafryd Manderly
Miklaz
Kezmya
Ezzara
Morgan
Merrel
Alf
Harwood Stout
Will Short
Barbrey Dustin
Roose Ryswell
Luton
Uthor
Moqorro
Belicho
? Fowler
Hop-Bean
Ash
Leaf
Scales
Black Knife
Snowylocks
Coals
Tom Barleycorn
Duncan Liddle
Luke
Leathers
Jax
Alysane Mormont
? Slate
Medrick
Rhodry
Henly
Walys
Daenerys Targaryen
Wun Weg Wun Dar Wun
Myrtle
Holly
Rowan
Beron
Morgan Liddle
Brandon Norrey
Hugo Wull
Artos Flint
Robin Peasebury
Lyra Mormont
Jorelle Mormont
Benjicot Branch
Harys Cobb
William Foxglove
Donnel Flint
Jack
Narbert Grandison
Benethon Scales
Brus Buckler
Patrek
Dorden
Malegorn
Lambert Whitewater
Perkin Follard
Tycho Nestoris
Dannel
Cregan Karstark
Tormo Fregar
Pynto
Gelmar
Nurse
Zahrina
Sweets
Hildy
Barba Bracken
Melissa Blackwood
Bethany Blackwood
Ben Blackwood
Robert Blackwood
Brynden Blackwood
Hoster Blackwood
Harry Rivers
Harry Merrell
Harsley
Lacey
Torghen Flint
Gylo Rhegan
Hero
Marghaz zo Loraq
Squirrel
Willow
Frenya
Tom Codd
Daegon Shepherd
Rodrik Sparr
Kerwin
Burton Humble
Longwater Pyke
Scar
Morgo
Viserys Plumm
Tybero Istarion
Kasporio
Maris
Fulk
Garrett
Dryn
Soren Shieldbreaker
Gerrick Kingsblood
Harle
Harle
Howd Wanderer
Brogg
Devyn Sealskinner
Kyleg
Morna
Harghaz
Beans
Malo Jayn
Brendel Byrne
Armond Connington
? Morrigen
Ronald Connington
Raymund Connington
Alynne Connington
Ronald Storm
Tristan
Dick Cole
Lymond Pease
Canty
Humfrey Clifton
Ormund Wylde
Ned Woods
Arthor Karstark
Fingers
Rook
Tom Tidewood
Steffar
Manfryd Merlyn
Izembaro
Robert Strong
Bokkoko
Snatch
Kem
Hammer
Kennet
Nail
Steelskin
Shiera Seastar
Grazdar
Azzak
Bhakaz
Dhazzar
Tumco Lho
Larraq
? Whent
Draqaz
Jezhene
Gavin
Doss
Ygon Oldfather
Tal Toraq
Jokin
Renfred Rykker
Tyrion Tanner
Earl Harlaw
Richard Morrigen
Arstan Selmy
Casper Wylde
Sebastion Errol
Clifford Swann
Mary Mertyns
Alysanne Lefford
Lorent Lorch
Tybolt Hetherspoon
Quentyn Qorgyle
Symon Santagar
Trebor Jordayne
Daeron Vaith
Jyana Reed
Bethany Bolton
Brandon Norrey
Torren Liddle
Rickard Liddle
Alyn Blackwood
Edmund Blackwood
Barbara Bracken
Jayne Bracken
Catelyn Bracken
Bess Bracken
Alysanne Bracken
Eleanor Tarly
Maynard Holt
Russ Barleycorn
Ferrego Antaryon
Qarro Volentin
Chezdhar zo Rhaezn
Maezon zo Rhaezn
Grazdhan zo Rhaezn
Torman Peake
Pykewood Peake
Caspor Hill
Humfrey Stone
Will Cole
Lorimas Mudd
Jon Lothston
Duncan Strong
Denys Strong
Chains
John Mudd
Uhlan

Comment: Is it necessary to copy the whole list into this answer when you are already linking to a spreadsheet that contains this information?

Comment: You can’t add all the names to one answer properly—I just tried. Getting them all out and into the right format was a fairly simple job, but the answer ended up being 83,655 characters long, which is almost 2.5 times the 30,000 character limit. If you skip chapters, titles, and formatting, it can be done, but it won’t be pretty. (I just added them all in in the un-pretty way; feel free to roll back if you think it ruins it and isn’t worth it.)

Comment: and, of course, this answer will become obsolete some time in 2019 when the next book is released :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you, that's brilliant! Any chance of bullet-pointing them all, or would even that be too many characters? (*If only there was a character limit on the books as well...*)

Comment: @Thunderforge no, but it looks awesome, +1

Comment: For anyone thinking that the names at the end of the list don't even look *slightly* familiar ("Chains", "Duncan Strong", "Jyana Reed", etc), apparently the last 52 in the list were only mentioned in the ADWD appendix. They're mostly other people in known households and factions (e.g. Chains and the Strongs are high-ranking Golden Company members, Jyana is Howland's wife, etc)

Comment: Now that's a long list. xD

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah, the bullet points take it over the limit. I think there are about 50 characters left to 30,000 as it is now.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I want to put this into columns :-)

Comment: You could cut down the letter-count by arranging them into family groups; Stark alone would save you nearly 500 characters.

Comment: I keep meaning to come back to this and edit it to use screenshots of the table instead of text. It'll look much better then, since there will be not only names but also enough info to distinguish (for instance) all the different Brandon Starks.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - At the very least, you could make it into a [nested scrollbox](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7429/20774)

Comment: @KutuluMike I too thought that the book would be released in the first quarter of 2019. I was wrong. I hope it is released in the remaining quarters of 2019.

Comment: @doubleOrt looks it's never coming anymore haha

Comment: Oh @doubleOrt, oh KutuluMike, such sweet summer children. Remember the days when everyone thought he'd _have_ to get book six out by 2016, otherwise he'd _hold up the TV show!_

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah it's a very messy situation. I remember that I was being fairly conservative when I made the 1st quarter of 2019 prediction. It's been 3 years.

Comment: Thanks for the credit - I was wondering if anyone had used my spreadsheet for something useful :). I think there are newer versions out there now by other Redditors though. Also, yes it's wonderful to think that we used to think that The Winds of Winter would come out in 2019 ...